# How to add margin around a View in MaterialAlertDialogBuilder?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I need more information from users when they click on a particular item (from a list). I am displaying a dialog in order to get more info and I am using MaterialAlertDialogBuilder. This is how I am building it:

```
val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_text_input, null)
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, R.style.AlertDialogMaterialTheme)
                .setTitle(R.string.ofi_pleaseDescribe)
                .setView(v)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { d, i ->
                    if (d == null) return@setPositiveButton
                    val txt = etInput.text?.trim()
                    etRationale.setText(txt)
                }
                .show()
```

This is its layout (view_text_input.xml).

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/ofi_textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etInput"
        style="@style/ofi_editText"
        android:hint="@string/ofi_title_hint" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

As you can see in the following screenshot, the above margins are getting ignored for some reason. Does anyone know why and how can I add margins around the view?

[image]

Comment: Added margin from what view? Try adding any layout as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something different in your view.

Something like:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
    android:paddingStart="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
    android:paddingEnd="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ...>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .../>
  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(AlertDialogActivity.this)
            .setTitle(R.string.ofi_pleaseDescribe)
            .setView(R.layout.view_text_input)
            ...
            .show();
```

[image]

Comment: oh, Thank you. It works like charm. Seems we cannot use TextInputLayout as a root view.

Comment: @Hesam yes you can use TextInputLayout as a root view. The outer FrameLayout is really not useful.